# How to install urllib.request on python 3.8.2

Tags: python, pip

I have a problem with installing the library `urllib`.
I have already tried:

```sh
$ python -m pip install urllib

$ pip install urllib.request 

$ pip install urllib3

$ pip install urllib2

$ pip install urllib2.request
```

And none of them work. Can someone tell me how to install this library?

The error I get is this:

```sh
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement urllib

ERROR: No matching distribution found for urllib
```

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: What's the error? Cannot reproduce with `pip install urllib3`.

Comment: also make sure you are using the right python!

Comment: the eror is: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Urllib
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Urllib

Answer (score 5):

[urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) is a standard library, you do not have to install it.

Simply use `import urllib` in your Python code.